# How to use ServiceCore framework from salesforce in a Xamarin forms app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, salesforce, xamarin.ios-binding

I am getting a warning in my console when I try building the app in Release configuration. The warning reads **The ServiceSDK frameworks have not been prepared for release.
Please ensure the "prepare-framework" script is run after the "Embed Frameworks" build phase.**

From the documentations, I understand that a build phase script has to be run to fix the issue.

***Here is how I use the framework in my solution:***

I am creating a binding library which refers the framework through a ***Native Reference***. Then I run the library project and build a .dll with I use in the iOS project within my Xamarin forms application. All this is working fine. I am able to use the intended features from the framework.

However, there is this warning which appears in the console when I run the App in Release configuration. Also, when I tried submitting the App to App Store, it throws error, which is apparently the same mentioned above.

I tried by adding Custom commands which I think is the equivalent of Xcode build phase scripts, but the warning doesn't simply go away.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Xamarin! What Custom commands have you tried? And where did you put them? Please share it so we can help more

Comment: @Sameer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/prepare_for_appstore.htm Here you can find the details of what I am trying to do. I tried adding this run script in Visual studio for mac as a custom command.

Comment: I understand, could you share a screen shot of where inside Visual Studio you placed this run command? (because the issue might be there)

Answer (score 0):

Sample Repos - https://github.com/XamarinUniversity/ENT302

Youtube Video Link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEypPXVoYnY&feature=youtu.be

Gudie Here - https://xamarinuniversity.github.io/ENT302/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in my case, I'm not using the salesforce SDK for authenticating the user. I use the ServiceCore SDK and ServiceChat SDK for implementing a chat feature. You can find the details in the following link [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/prepare_for_appstore.htm).